# Facing Issues in Recursion of Perfect Number Problem

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion, perfect-numbers

I've been working on the scala recursion problem. I used to develop the program using loops and then use the concept of recursion to convert the existing loop problem in a recursive solution.
So I have written the following code to find the perfect number using loops.

```
  def isPerfect(n: Int): Boolean = {
    var sum = 1
    // Find all divisors and add them
    var i = 2
    while ( {
      i * i <= n
    }) {
      if (n % i == 0) if (i * i != n) sum = sum + i + n / i
      else sum = sum + i

      i += 1
    }
    // If sum of divisors is equal to
    // n, then n is a perfect number
    if (sum == n && n != 1) return true
    false
  }
```

Here is my attempt to convert it into a recursive solution. But I'm getting the incorrect result.

```
  def isPerfect(n: Int): Boolean = {
    var sum = 1
    // Find all divisors and add them
    var i = 2
    def loop(i:Int, n:Int): Any ={
      if(n%i == 0) if (i * i != n) return sum + i + n / i
      else
        return loop(i+1, sum+i)
    }
    val sum_ = loop(2, n)
    // If sum of divisors is equal to
    // n, then n is a perfect number
    if (sum_ == n && n != 1) return true
    false
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a tail-recursive solution

```
def isPerfectNumber(n: Int): Boolean = {
  @tailrec def loop(d: Int, acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    if (d == 1) 1 :: acc
    else if (n % d == 0) loop(d - 1, d :: acc)
    else loop(d - 1, acc)
  }
  loop(n-1, Nil).sum == n
}
```

As a side-note, functions that have side-effects such as state mutation scoped **locally** are still considered pure functions as long as the mutation is not visible externally, hence having while loops in such functions might be acceptable.